# I want to better organize my website files, but I can access the .php files using the folder hierarchy. How can I override that?

Tags: php, apache, organization, project-organization

For example, to access a page in my search folder, I have to write:

mywebsite.tld/search/searchJob.php

I don't want users to have to write down folder structure and whatnot. What can I do to change this?

OR, is there a better way to organize my files? Because I'm only two pages in and I decided to move some files and got lost in the hierarchy (that's why I moved them like in the picture).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Apache web server, you could use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to beautify the URLs so that users don't have to type in everything. For example, users open `mywebsite.tld/search/` and the request will be processed by `mywebsite.tld/search/searchJob.php` without the user noticing it. This has another big advantage: You can organize the files as you want, and change the file names arbitrarily - you'll only have to change the URL mapping when you move or rename a PHP file.

As an aside: Users will *almost never* type in a *full* URL, normal users click through the main page or use enhanced address bars (like the Firefox address bar which shows history items) to open a web page.

Answer (score 1):

Three main options:

1. You can use Apache's [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html).
2. You can hack your own URL handler, by parsing `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

   ```
   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/jobs") {
       require_once("search/searchJob.php");
   }
   ```
3. Use a web framework that properly handles URLs for you.

Comment: Which one uses less resources/easier to maintain? Do you have a tutorial somewhere where I could learn? :)